# Need to extract data which is in tabular format from a python list

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
                           Team A              Team B

   name                     xyz                 abc
  addres                   345,JH colony       43,JK colony
  Phone                    76576               87866

  name                     pqr                 ijk
  addres                   345,ab colony       43,JKkk colony
  Phone                    7666666               873336
```

Here above , I have 2 teams with names, address and phone number of each player in a list . However, there are no tables as such, but the data whiloe i tried to read is in Tabular format, where In team A Team B are 2nd and 3rd columns and the 1st column is where the tags name,address phone comes.
My objective is to fetch only the names of the players grouped by team name. In this example, there are 2 players each team. it can be between 1 and 2.Is there a way someone can help to share a solution using Regular Expressions. I tried a bit, however that is giving me random results , such as team B players in Team A.Can someone help?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about how you are receiving this data. You describe it as in Tabular format, but that is not really clear to me. Does it come from a long string? In the question header you describe the data coming from a python list, what does that data look like? Maybe you can post the code you are using to shed more light on this.

Comment: Above is how it looks in the document. After I tried converting it in to a list, it was random and I had the issue which I mentioned. @VectorVictor

Comment: Is the document one long string? Are you using a Jupyter notebook? Are you opening from a file? Are you using a copy/paste from a document. It is very hard to answer your question without this information.

Comment: Yes, the document is a long string. Yes I am using juputer notebook.I am reading the entire document as a .npy file which has long string. after having read the file form a .npy , it turns into a numpy.ndarray.NO, I am not using a copy paste from a document. The document was a pdf which was extracted first and then it was loaded as a .npy file. The npy file was of shape (1,2) 1--for the number of documents. 2- for the elements( one of which is a document Id and the other is the long text of which is a part of the text in the question.

Comment: You can do a loop instead of trying to do with regex. Sometimes, regex doesn't value the effort. I cloud select the variables  with "((name[ ]+)([\w\d]+)[ ]+([\w\d]+))", but grouping it's not very common, mate. Check it out: https://regex101.com/r/MKATcS/1

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, in future I would give more detail on your input string, I have assumed spaces. If it uses tabs, try replacing them with four spaces. I have added an extra row which included a more difficult case.

Warning: If Team B has more players than Team A, it will probably put the extra players in Team A. But it will depend on the exact formatting.

```
import re

pdf_string = '''                         Team A              Team B

   name                     xyz                 abc
   addres                   345,JH colony       43,JK colony
   Phone                    76576               87866

   name                     pqr                 ijk
   addres                   345,ab colony       43,JKkk colony
   Phone                    7666666               873336

   name                     forename surname    
   addres                   345,ab colony       
   Phone                    7666666             '''

lines_untrimmed = pdf_string.split('\n')

lines = [line.strip() for line in lines_untrimmed]

space_string = ' ' * 3 #  3 spaces to allow spaces between names and teams

# This can be performed as a one liner below, but I wrote it out for an explanation
lines_csv = []
for line in lines:
    line_comma_spaced = re.sub(space_string + '+', ',', line)
    line_item_list = line_comma_spaced.split(',')
    lines_csv.append(line_item_list)
# lines_csv = [re.sub(space_string + '+', ',', line).split(',') for line in lines]


teams = lines_csv[0]

team_dict = {team:[] for team in teams}

for line in lines_csv:
    if 'name' in line:
        line_abbv = line[1:]  # [1:] to remove name
        for i, team in enumerate(teams):
            if i < len(line_abbv):  # this will prevent an error if there are fewer names than teams
                team_dict[team].append(line_abbv[i])
print(team_dict)
```

This will give the output:

```
{'Team A': ['xyz', 'pqr', 'forename surname'], 'Team B': ['abc', 'ijk', 'ijk']}
```